# Questions about a plot in python

Tags: python, matplotlib

Can someone tell me how can I make the kind of plot in the figure below in Python (not sure how it is called)? Thank you!

[image]

Comment: what have you tried so far?  can you post your code/attempt ?

Comment: this is called "axes zoom effect" in matplotlib and their gallery has an example that demonstrates how to do it.

Comment: @PaulH Thanks a lot! I didn't know what to search for!